# Is $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O)$ finitely generated?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $F$ be a number field and $\mathcal O$ its integer ring: is $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathcal O)$ finitely generated?

It's well known that $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ is generated by $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $S=\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

It seems easy enough when $\mathcal O$ is a Euclidean domain, because then we can replace $T$ with $T_i:=\begin{pmatrix}1&x_i\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ where $\mathcal O=\bigoplus x_i\mathbf Z$ and use the algebraic proof [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf).

But what happens when $\mathcal O$ is not a Euclidean domain?

Comment: I believe you also need to use that the group of units is finitely generated in the algebraic proof.

Comment: @mercio I admit I didn't notice that detail, but the group of units is always finitely generated anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Vaserstein proved, that if $R$ is a Dedekind ring of arithmetic type with infinitely many units then  $SL_2(R) = E_2(R)$ holds, where
$E_2(R)$ denotes the subgroup of $SL_2(R)$ generated by the elementary matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & r \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ r & 1\end{pmatrix}$ with $r \in R$. We can apply this for rings of integers, provided 
that the *unit group* is infinite. By Dirichlet’s unit theorem, a ring of integers $R$ of an algebraic number field $K$ has finitely many units if and only if $K$ is either the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ or an imaginary quadratic number field. Under this assumption P. M. Cohn proved that $SL_2(R) = E_2(R)$ if and only if $R$ is Euclidean with respect to complex modulus. This leaves only the cases $F = \Bbb Q(\sqrt{-D})$ for $D$ any squarefree integer different from $1,2,3,7,11 $. Then $SL_2(\mathcal O)$ is *not* generated by the elementary matrices.  However, the index of the subgroup generated by elementary matrices in $SL_2(\mathcal O)$ is finite, so we can add a finite number of non-elementary matrices to the generating set, to ensure $SL_2(\mathcal O)$ will be generated by this set.

So it is finitely generated in all cases.

Reference (with many examples and explicit calculations): [Generators and relations for certain special linear groups](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwjRtYHJg-_SAhUKJcAKHc_JCeMQFghcMAY&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fdownload%2Fpdf_1%2Feuclid.bams%2F1183529640&usg=AFQjCNFOocRF6gj_PlEMpg7Bve1SZdze5Q&sig2=mZCCB7RBKjUT7a2Ah5dtxw) by R. G. Swan.

Comment: I don't get it. Since $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & r \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & r +s\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, if $R$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$ module then $\{{\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 1 & r \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}}, r \in R\}$ is finite generated

Comment: The problem is that $\{{\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1}\end{pmatrix}}, a \in R^\times\}$ is finitely generated iff the group of units is finitely generated, that's it ?